# Trying to get HTML 5 form to submit data

Tags: html

Trying to get form data to submit to my email address. Not too sure what is wrong with the code, as no data is being sent.

```
<!-- BEGIN SAMPLE FORM PORTLET-->
<div class="portlet box green ">
    <div class="portlet-title">
        <div class="caption"> <i class="fa fa-gift"></i> Horizontal Form</div>
        <div class="tools"> <a href="" class="collapse">
                    </a>
 <a href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal" class="config">
                    </a>
 <a href="" class="reload">
                    </a>
 <a href="" class="remove">
                    </a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-body form">
        <form action="myemailaddress@gmail.com" method="post">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Block Help</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text"> <span class="help-block">
                             A block of help text.
                          </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Inline Help</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-inline input-medium" enter code hereplaceholder="Enter text"> <span class="help-inline">
                             Inline help.
                          </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"></div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions fluid">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn green">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END SAMPLE FORM PORTLET-->
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your form action to some sort of CGI script that's capable of catching the form POST and formatting it into an email message. PHP, perl, etc...

Here is basic PHP example...  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp